# How to assign value to key hashmap Perl?

Tags: perl, hashmap

I have the code bellow. I want to assign for each version values but somehow I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
%buildsMap = ();
#read schedule
opendir (DIR, $buildsDir) or die $!;
while ( my $file = readdir DIR ) {
    if (($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)-DVD/) || ($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)/)) {
        foreach $version(@versionS){
            if ($1 eq $version ){
               @temp = @{$buildsMap{$version}};
               push @temp,$file;
               @{$buildsMap{$version}} = @temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to use the keys from this hashmap it is ok. Please advice me.

Comment: Could you give an example of input (ie. the filenames in $buildsDir) and the expected output?  Also, what is in `@versionS`?

Comment: There are just some folders readed by if (($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)-DVD/).... and if the folders meet the condition they should be assigns as values to the keys $version. @versionS is an array of versions from where I;m using just $version(a couple of version necessary for my script). I'm tring to have an output like this: foreach $version (keys %buildsMap){
        print $values
        }

Comment: have you thought about using `strict` and `warnings`? Also it's still not clear what `@versionS` contains, could you edit your code with some example data ( like `my @versions= ('V132", 'V432')`

Answer (score 3):

First order of business, turn on strict and warnings.  This will discover any typo'd variables and other mistakes.  The major issue here will be you have to declare all your variables.  Fixing that all up, and printing out the resulting `%buildMap`, we have a minimum viable example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $buildsDir = shift;
my @versionS = qw(V111 V222 V333);
my %buildsMap = ();

#read schedule
opendir (DIR, $buildsDir) or die $!;
while ( my $file = readdir DIR ) {
    if (($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)-DVD/) || ($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)/)) {
        foreach my $version (@versionS) {
            if ($1 eq $version ){
               my @temp = @{$buildsMap{$version}};
               push @temp,$file;
               @{$buildsMap{$version}} = @temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

for my $version (keys %buildsMap) {
    my $files = $buildsMap{$version};

    say "$version @$files";
}
```

Which gives the error `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at test.plx line 15.`.  That's this line.

```
            my @temp = @{$buildsMap{$version}};
```

The problem here is how you're working with array references.  That specific line fails because if `$buildsMap{$version}` has no entry you're trying to dereference nothing and Perl won't allow that, not for a normal dereference.  We could fix that, but there's better ways to work with hashes of lists.  Here's what you have.

```
           my @temp = @{$buildsMap{$version}};
           push @temp,$file;
           @{$buildsMap{$version}} = @temp;
```

That copies out all the filenames into `@temp`, works with `@temp` and the more comfortable syntax, and copies them back in.  It's inefficient for memory and amount of code.  Instead, we can do it in place.  First by initializing the value to an empty array reference, if necessary, and then by pushing the file onto that array reference directly.

```
            $buildsMap{$version} ||= [];
            push @{$buildsMap{$version}}, $file;
```

`||=` is the `or-equals` operator.  It will only do the assignment if the left-hand side is false.  It's often used to set default values.  You could also write `$buildsMap{$version} = [] if !$buildsMap{$version}` but that rapidly gets redundant.

But we don't even need to do that!  `push` is a special case.  For convenience, you can dereference an empty value and pass it to `push`!  So we don't need the initializer, just push.

```
            push @{$buildsMap{$version}}, $file;
```

---

While the code works, it could be made more efficient.  Instead of scanning `@versionS` for every filename, potentially wasteful if there's a lot of files or a lot of versions, you can use a hash.  Now there's no inner loop needed.

```
my %versionS = ( 'V111' => 1, 'V222' => 2, 'V333' => 3 );

...

if (($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)-DVD/) || ($file =~ /(V\d\d\d.*)/)) {
    my $version = $1;
    if ($versionS{$version}){
        push @{$buildsMap{$version}}, $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you `use v5.10`, you also could advice the `//=` operator, since it always checks for definedness, what is most likely that what someone wants. In this specific case it's okay to use, because we know from the program structure that the hash shouldn't contain any false values (as references are true (I hope)). But that is one more unnecessary hurdle to jump for the person reading your code (which is most likely the programmer himself in three months). On the other hand `//=` is quite new (just eight years old), so it could be that the future reader isn't accustomed to the newer ways yet.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Good question. I specifically did not use `//=` here. There are many cases where `//=` is more correct than `||=`, usually to retain `0` and `""` as valid values. This is not one of them. I specifically chose `||=` because if a hash entry is incorrectly set to `0` or `""` it should be replaced with an empty list. This makes the code more robust, good enough for a short lived variable like `%buildsMap`. If you want more checks than that you should instead write a class and control access to the data through methods.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. On a similar note, one could eliminate `%versionS` and the `||=` check entirely by preallocating version lists in `%buildMap`. Initialize it with `my %buildMap = map { $_ => [] } qw(V111 V222 V333)` and then `push @{$buildMap{$1}}, $file if $buildMap{$1}`. I avoided that both because the answer was getting long, and it overloads the meaning of `%buildMap` in ways potentially confusing to the original poster and future maintainers. If `%versionS` was big it might be justified to save some memory. Again, once you start doing things like that it's better to write a class.

Comment: *“if a hash entry is incorrectly set to `0` or `""` it should be replaced with an empty list”* I'm not so sure. If a hash value is anything other than an array reference then there is a bug in the code, and making it work silently regardless disables the diagnostics that `use strict 'refs'` provides. I think I'd prefer my code to die with `Can't use string "0" as an array ref while strict refs in use`. After all, that bug may be overwriting a legitimate array reference with 0 and so losing data